# loading image from a sql database to tableview cell

Tags: iphone

```
ContactInfo *data = [self.contacts objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

cell.textLabel.text = data.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = data.designation;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:data.image ofType:@"png"];

NSLog(@"%@",filePath);

UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
cell.imageView.image = image1;

return cell;
```

Here i get the right cell data and the detail text label but the image view does not come it takes some other image with . If any one can advice .

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve image from database as NSData and then initialise your image object with this NSData object,

```
  NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:data.image ofType:@"png"];
  NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];

  UIImage *itemImage=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData cache:YES] ;
```

Now use this image object as

```
cell.imageView.image = itemImage;
```

For more information you can follow [Fetch image from database in Iphone](http://iphonetut.com/sqlite/160/fetch_image_from_database_in_iphone)